# Excel increase / decrease decimal based on kg/gr

Tags: excel, excel-formula, decimal, rounding

In my sheet I'm weighing 4 samples. I need to report the average of these samples so I've written a simple function. However for customer #1 I need to report them in KG's with 1 decimal and to customer 2 I need to report them in Gr's with 0 decimals. So I wrote the formula below:

```
=IF(test="customer#1";ROUND(AVERAGE(M26:O29);1);ROUND(AVERAGE(M26:O37);0);
```

This calculates the values correctly however the GR's still display 1 decimal (.0) even though it doesn't get calculated. Is it possible to tell Excel to subtract a decimal when using grams but add it when using kilograms.

I've tried to with conditional formatting which displays the correct number but the decimal is still "hiding" beneath the surface.

Comment: If it is essentially still the same number, why does it matter that the decimal is still "hiding"?

Comment: Does it help if you set the cell format to General instead of Number? This should hide the decimal

Comment: I guess you could use `Text` to format the number.  `=TEXT(ROUND(AVERAGE(M26:O29),IF(test="Customer#1",1,0)),IF(test="Customer#1","0.0","0"))`

Comment: I switched the cell format to General instead and it works! Who would've thought the solution was so simple. Thank you so much!